# why alert is not display while using pure function in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

https://plnkr.co/edit/eCZSo6Rl5odN1hTb6BCW?p=preview

Hi

i am implementing row `component` which will add when user fill item in input field and press `add` button

```
var listItems = this.props.names.map(function(d, idx){
      return (<r key={idx}></r>)
    })
```

but it not show alert when we try to add component

```
const r = (props) => {
    alert('---')
    return (
        <li>
            <span>hiii</span>
        </li>
    );
};
```

any update ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your JSX.

```
return (<r key={idx}></r>)
```

Lowercase tags are assumed to be built-in HTML. To refer to user-defined classes and functions, you need to use an uppercase name. So React is looking for a standard HTML `<r>` tag.

If you change your function to `R`, things should work.

See the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for details.

Comment: but I am using redux in y example

Comment: @user944513 - You're right; I'd overlooked that. So, is it working now?

Comment: actually I pass props like that `  <r names ={this.props.names}/>`

Comment: So from your answer I think "I will not make separate component of list  " ?  correct ?

Comment: I deleted my previous (incorrect) answer and put in a correct one.

Answer (score -1):

```
return (<r key={idx}></r>)
```

change to

```
return (<R key={idx}></R>)

const R = (props) => {
    alert('---')
    return (
        <li>
            <span>hiii</span>
        </li>
    );
};
```

Comment: It always a good idea to leave a comment with your code suggestion so it's clear for others why you think this solves the problem.